# Is there a correct Pythonic version of this loop?

Tags: python, numpy

In converting a nice simple loop to a more pythonic version, I introduced a subtle (well, fine, subtle is in the eye of the beholder) bug.

The data structure is three 1D arrays:

- `sums[10]` of floats
- `indices[2]` of integers in [0,10);
  i.e., indices into sum[]
- `how_much[2]` of floats

Original code:

```
for i in range(2):  
    sums[indices[i]] += how_much[i]
```

So if `sums` starts all zeros, and `indices=[3,4]` and `how_much=[.1,.2]`, then we will set `sums[3]=.1` and `sums[4]=.2`.

Pythonic version:

```
sums[indices] += how_much
```

All fine -- except for the corner case when `indices[0] == indices[1]`. So if `sums` again starts all zeros, `indices=[3,3]` and `how_much=[.1, .2]`... then
the first loop sets `sums[3]=.3`, while the Pythonic "equivalent" sets `sums[3]=.2`.

I've not found this case specifically addressed in the documentation, but I'll concede that numpy is operating reasonably. Unfortunately, that behavior is incorrect for my application.

Can anyone think of a nice Pythonic way to implement the loop? (Of course, in real life, the arrays are much larger, and I execute the loop many times).

Comment: As a side comment, you should probably pick a different name than sum for the array, because that is already a reserved keyword, and you are overwriting it locally

Comment: `where` is a reserved keyword in NumPy.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Absolutely not. Moreover, since NumPy is a Python-based library, it cannot have its own reserved words.

Comment: Ok, wrong choice of words. I meant, `where` is a function in NumPy.

Comment: `sum` is also a function, not a keyword.

Comment: I've edited the variable names to eliminate the redefinition of existing functions. /JoelG

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the existing question/answer. Numpy.add.at() will work just fine for me.